# Create a column based on similarity to other rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a df with guests, sorted by family. The number of members in a family is not fixed. Two different families may have the same familyhead name (e.g. "abba").

```
   family fam_head  name    meeting1  meeting2 meeting3  meeting4
0    1     True     abba     1            1      1          1 
1    1              ben      1            1      1          1
2    1              berry                                   1 
3    2              jack     1                              1
4    2     True     joe      1                              1
5    3              razia    1                              1
6    3     True     riri                  1                 
7    4     True     abba    ... 
...
```

For each family head, how could I create a column in normal English (with use of commas + 'and' before the last person's name). It needs to list the events only when members within a family are invited to different things:

```
1    abba    Hi abba, delighted for you, ben and berry to come.

             meeting1, meeting2 and meeting 3: abba and ben           (events with same members grouped)
             meeting4: abba, ben and berry

2    joe     Hi joe, delighted for you and jack to come.              (no need to specify events since all members invited to same meetings)
                                                         

3    riri    Hi riri, delighted for you and razia to come.
             
             meeting1 and meeting 4: razia
             meeting2: riri

4   abba     Hi abba, ...
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

A possible option :

```
MCOLS = df.filter(like="meeting").columns # or hardcoded

def comma_nd(inp):
    import re
    return re.sub(
        r",(?!.*,)", " and",
        ", ".join(list(inp)) if not isinstance(inp, str) else inp,
    )

def greet(g):
    def get_events():
        return (
            ((tmp := g.set_index("name")[MCOLS].T.dropna(how="all"))
             .fillna(0).astype(bool) @ (tmp.columns + ", "))
             .str.strip(", ").reset_index().pipe(
                lambda x: x.groupby(x[0].map(comma_nd).tolist())
                 ["index"].agg(comma_nd).to_dict())
        )

    return (
        TPL.render(
            **{
                "head": (h := g.at[g["fam_head"].idxmax(), "name"]),
                "others": comma_nd(g.sort_values("fam_head")
                            ["name"].replace(h, "you")),
                "same_meeting": g.duplicated(MCOLS, keep=False).all(),
                "events": get_events(),
            }
        ).strip()
    )
```

Output :

```
# greetings = df.groupby("family").apply(greet, include_groups=False) # 2.2.0
# print(greetings.str.cat(sep=f"\n{'-'*50}\n"))

Hi abba, delighted for you, ben and berry to come.

meeting1, meeting2 and meeting3: abba and ben
meeting4: abba, ben and berry
--------------------------------------------------
Hi joe, delighted for you and jack to come.
--------------------------------------------------
Hi riri, delighted for you and razia to come.

meeting1 and meeting4: razia
meeting2: riri
```

Now, if you want to include the `greetings` in the original `df`, you can use one of these :

```
# If you want to fill only the rows of the heads :
df.loc[df["fam_head"], "greet_card"] = greetings.to_numpy()

# Or if you want to fill all the rows of each family, use :
df = df.merge(greetings.rename("greet_card"), left_on="family", right_index=True)
```

Used [Template](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/) :

```
# pip install Jinja2
from jinja2 import Template

TPL = Template("""
Hi {{ head }}, delighted for {{ others }} to come.

{% for meetings, attendees in events.items() -%}
{% if not same_meeting -%}
{{ attendees }}: {{ meetings }}
{% endif -%}
{% endfor -%}
""")
```

Used input :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "family": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        "fam_head": [True, None, None, None, True, None, True],
        "name": ["abba", "ben", "berry", "jack", "joe", "razia", "riri"],
        "meeting1": [1, 1, None, 1, 1, 1, None],
        "meeting2": [1, 1, None, None, None, None, 1],
        "meeting3": [1, 1, None, None, None, None, None],
        "meeting4": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, None],
    }
).convert_dtypes()
```

Comment: 1) how could I add a blank line, with a line below that saying "thank you" (When I try adding it to the bottom of ```TPL```, it only leaves a blank line in the case when the events are not listed)

2) If the family has one member, there should be no events listed. How could I update the code to do this please?

Comment: I'll make sure to handle the two points you mention if you provide a meaningful Input/Output.